# jQuery - If previous element doesnt have specific class then remove that element

Tags: jquery, element

I wrote this code, but it doesnt work.

goal:

1. If span that is previous to ".well-well" is NOT ".dont-remove" then remove that span
2. However if span that is previous to ".well-well" IS ".dont-remove" then do nothing

"example" here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sAebR/

```
if( $(".well-well").prev('span').not('.dont-remove') ){ $(".well-well").prev('span').remove(); }
```

What im getting with this code is that it removes all spans that are previous to ".well-well" and i have no idea why.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need the if:

```
$(".well-well").prev('span').not('.dont-remove').remove()
```

what your code is say is:

```
if ($(".well-well").prev('span').not('.dont-remove') != null) 
{
 //remove them all
}
```

don't worry about the if. The remove() function will look after that.

http://jsfiddle.net/sAebR/2/

Comment: @JamesKhoury well-well.. i shouldve seen that coming :) Thanks!

Comment: @zneak yea, i find it sort of weird that you cant declare answer correct untill like after 10+ minutes i believe.

Comment: @Lollero Oh right, I forgot this restriction. I mentioned it because you seem new to Stack Overflow; it's great if you picked it up already.

Comment: @Lollero i think thats so you don't just select the first one that "seems" right but you explore some alternatives? Thats just a guess.

Comment: @JamesKhoury I suppose so. I got thinking.. what if i wanted to say "if theres any class at all dont remove" ?

Comment: @JamesKhoury would this be ok to use? $(".well-well").prev('span').not('[class]').remove();

Comment: @Lollero i think it needs to be `.not('span[class]')`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how you remove elements. If you find elements that match your criteria, you remove every element (with no specific criteria).

It's perfectly legal to use `remove` on empty collections, so you shouldn't worry about if there are elements or not. Try this instead:

```
$(".well-well").prev('span').not('.dont-remove').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `not` statement is always evaluating `true` because it returns a jQuery object and therefore you are removing all spans.

jQuery works on collections and is chainable. You can simply combine them all into this:

```
$(".well-well").prev('span').not('.dont-remove').remove();
```

Check it out in action - http://jsfiddle.net/WFTbF/1/